# How can I use IloCplex::readSolution() and after query cplex class instance to obtain var. values and other values?

Tags: c++, cplex

I need to read an incumbent solution stored before in a .sol file an then use instance of IloCplex as after having call 'solve'.
I need to write something like:

```
iloNumVar var(0.0,1.0,ILOBOOL,"var_name");
...
cplex.readSolution("incumbent.sol");
cplex.getObjValue();
cplex.getValue(var);
```

Any call as cplex.get* throws except.
What can I do to reach my aim?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the exact error you get? Also, is your `var` supposed to be binary? in this case it'd be better to use `IloInt` type.

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception. This is the error, I can't know more. I don't think the type of the variable is involved in; when I run my program without trying to load a before .sol everything goes well.

Comment: Only when it read the .sol tell me this: 'Warning, line 1090865: 'x68571' is not a variable'. I give a name to all the variable I initialize but seems cplex use by default the var 'x68571' (wiht "bound ... = 0") in obj. func. I have not found a way to give my self a name to this var...

Comment: Is it correct that you model a linear program, solve it, then write the solution to a .sol file and after that you read the solution and try to print it by using `cplex.getValue`?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do this, I need to be able to restart the optimization exactly where it was stopped; plus I need get vars value to fill some data structures.

Comment: I still don't see why you would *ever* write the solution to a file and then re-read it. Why not just get the values you need direct from the IloCplex object?

Answer (score 1):

"CPLEX read SOL files as an advanced start. SOL files contain basis statuses, if they are available, and solution values. The basis statuses can be used for advanced starts with simplex optimizers; the solution values can be used for a crossover from a barrier solution or as a MIP start from a mixed integer solution. A mixed integer solution may be from a conventional MIP optimization or from a member of the solution pool." Technically you need to solve the LP with `cplex.solve()` before calling cplex.get* methods. Otherwise, if one reads the solution and calls cplex.get* methods without calling `cplex.solve()` Cplex throws `CPLEX Error  1217: No solution exists.`

So the best use of `IloCplex::readSolution` and `IloCplex::writeSolution` methods is to solve the model, write the solution, then modify the model if needed, read the solution, then call `cplex.solve()` and after that call cplex.get*

Also, I would suggest to read the optimal values as follows:

```
IloNumVarArray vars(env); // plus your bounds and  type
...
IloNumArray vals(env);
cplex.getValues(vals, vars);
```

Comment: Great thanks. I hoped was not like this. I have to find other ways to reach my aim... Have you some suggestion? I'm looking something that let me able to write a solution on a file and read it in a second time to restart the optimization, I supposed cplex offer me something to do this, let me avoid to write my own code... Now I'm looking around ">>" and "<<"  operators, they look weel to save my time in writing i/o code... Best regards.

Comment: Just call `cplex.readSolution` right before the next `cplex.solve()` call, and that's it, Cplex will take this solution as a warm start.

Comment: Yes, this will be a solution if I don't need to keep values from the solution before call `cplex.solve()`; when you call `cplex.solve()`, also if you ask to it to goes out any time it as an incumbent sol, you can't be sure to have only an evaluation of the provided solution with the consequent possibility to call `cplex.get*`; I'm working on a matheuristic alg., since I need to get values before call `.solve()`. I follow the way using `operator<<` and `operator>>` provided by `IloNUm*` classes, seems working for now; there is not to work a lot in i/o around those.

Comment: So, are you trying to evaluate (estimate) the solution without calling `cplex.solve()`?

Comment: No, I need to load a solution and restore my own program data as are when optimization end. i hoped file format .sol could be useful to load all variables involved and not just those I already write out becouse are those are interesting for practical use, merely, if I reload those, cplex optimize other vars and I'can't restart it exactly from the point it was before. But I have found other way, I write out all I need with `>>` and the read it with `<<`. Well! Bye, have a nice day! ;-)